# codeigniter Session in Safari browser

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

We are using the following to check session on all our controller functions.

```
$this->session->userdata('Admin_logged_in')
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

But on iPhone X using the Safari browser, it returns an empty value. The session Array is not getting set for each function, so the user is unable to log into the interface.

Here are different solutions we tried:

CodeIgniter 3 Session not working on Safari

http://mydons.com/fixed-mac-os-safari-codeigniter-sessionloginauthentication-issue/

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63184.html

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2880

If the session is removed from the function, the user is able to log in and the function runs properly. This issue appears for all Codeigniter Projects we develop.

Checking session:

```
public function index()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('Admin_logged_in')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('Admin_logged_in');
        $id = $session_data['userId'];
        $data['Headding']="Dashboard";
        $this->template->load('admin_layout', 'contents', 'admin/Admin_Dashboard', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('Admin', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Where session is set:

```
$sess_array = array();
foreach ($result as $result) {
    $sess_array = array( 
        'userId' => $result->userId, 
        'mobile' => $result->mobile, 
        'email'  => $result->email, 
        'status' => $result->status, 
        'RoleID' => $ans['roleId'], 
    );
}
$this->session->set_userdata('Admin_logged_in', $sess_array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you check with **Admin_logged_in** and set session with **User_logged_in**? Check your session again especially where you set your session.

I think you are using the wrong name to check the session.

Comment: its just mentioned there. But it is Admin_logged_in in both sides. @Robin Singh

Comment: Your code is perfect no further error, i tried this code on my browser it runs fine.

Comment: Kindly check in iPhone Safari Browser @Robin

Comment: Where I need to add var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); ?