# codeigniter Session Problem in Safari browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, mobile-safari

We are using the following to check session on all our controller functions.

$this->session->userdata('Admin_logged_in')

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

But on iPhone X using the Safari browser, it returns an empty value. The session Array is not getting set for each function, so the user is unable to log into the interface.

If the session is removed from the function, the user is able to log in and the function runs properly. This issue appears for all Codeigniter Projects we develop.

Here are the different solutions we tried:

CodeIgniter 3 Session not working on Safari

http://mydons.com/fixed-mac-os-safari-codeigniter-sessionloginauthentication-issue/

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63184.html

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2880

Checking session:

```
public function index()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('Admin_logged_in')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('Admin_logged_in');
        $id = $session_data['userId'];
        $data['Headding']="Dashboard";
        $this->template->load('admin_layout', 'contents', 'admin/Admin_Dashboard', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('Admin', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Where the session is set:

```
$sess_array = array();
foreach ($result as $result) {
    $sess_array = array( 
        'userId' => $result->userId, 
        'mobile' => $result->mobile, 
        'email'  => $result->email, 
        'status' => $result->status, 
        'RoleID' => $ans['roleId'], 
    );
}
$this->session->set_userdata('Admin_logged_in', $sess_array);
```

[codeigniter Session in Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374386/codeigniter-session-in-safari-browser)

Nobody gave Proper answer. The solution is given like [Issue with Codeigniter sessions on Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685171/issue-with-codeigniter-sessions-on-iphone).

But Where I need to add var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); ?

Answer (score 0):

dude... try to store only id of user and check .. if it works.. use auth library ... which is available... and do one more thing .. in config change

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'yourfoldername/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
```

and create yourfoldername folder at path where you `.htaccess` and `index.php` file is availabel